# Italics in titles?

Tags: support, status-declined

Normally the title of a film is in italics, and although this can be done with enclosing asterisks in the body of a question, this does not work in question titles.

Is there a way to put text in italics in titles?

Comment: As a note, for the most part it's not important since we generally don't find titles to be necessary in questions... the tags do that usually. Yes, there are some occasions where titles are useful but it's uncommon.

Answer (score 6):

### Unfortunately, no.

Markdown isn't supported in titles, and this is apparently not something Stack Exchange is willing to change; see [Can we get markdown support in Question's `title` field?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237125/can-we-get-markdown-support-in-questions-title-field) on main meta.

For film titles, you could use either "quotation marks", 'single quotes', or simply the name of the film standing on its own, without any asterisks or inverted commas or anything.